# timer in react function best approach

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a function that on button click creates a countdown timer that on completition hides a series of numbers and reveals an input as below,

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { requireAuth } from "util/auth.js";
import Sidebar_Users from "components/dashboard/Sidebar/Sidebar_Users";
import MindVaultSection from "components/dashboard/MindVault/MindVaultSection";
import BottomNavigation from "../../components/dashboard/BottomNavigation/BottomNavigation";


function makeid(length) {
    var result           = '';
    var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
       result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
 }


  function Baseline(props) {
    const [wStatus, setWStatus] = useState("completed"); // walkthrough Status
    var [time, setTime] = useState()


    // RandomString generates a random string of length n
    const numbers = makeid(7)

  
    useEffect(() => {

    }, []);
    function handleClick(e) {
      setTime(5)
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('The link was clicked.');
    }
   
    return (

        
      <>
      
        <Sidebar_Users dashboard={"Progress Map"}>
          <div>Working Memory Test</div>
          <div>You are about to do a small short term memory test.  A few letters will 
flash
on your computer monitor for 3 seconds.  Your job is to write down as many
letters as you can remember</div>


<div className="bg-white rounded-lg shadow p-4 items-center justify-center">{numbers}</div>
<div className="bg-white rounded-lg shadow p-4 items-center justify-center">{time}</div>

    <div className="bg-white rounded-lg shadow p-4 items-center justify-center">
        <div className="font-thin px-2 pb-4 text-lg">Enter your pin code</div>
        <div className="flex">
            <div    >
                <input className="h-16 w-12 border mx-2 rounded-lg flex items-center text-center font-thin text-3xl" value="" maxlength="1" max="9" min="0" inputmode="decimal"/>
                <input className="h-16 w-12 border mx-2 rounded-lg flex items-center text-center font-thin text-3xl" value="" maxlength="1" max="9" min="0" inputmode="decimal"/>
                <input className="h-16 w-12 border mx-2 rounded-lg flex items-center text-center font-thin text-3xl" value="" maxlength="1" max="9" min="0" inputmode="decimal"/>
                <input className="h-16 w-12 border mx-2 rounded-lg flex items-center text-center font-thin text-3xl" value="" maxlength="1" max="9" min="0" inputmode="decimal"/>
                <input className="h-16 w-12 border mx-2 rounded-lg flex items-center text-center font-thin text-3xl" value="" maxlength="1" max="9" min="0" inputmode="decimal"/>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<button onClick={handleClick} className="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent text-base leading-6 bg-gradient-to-r from-pink-500 to-orange-500 hover:from-teal-600 hover:to-green-300   text-white font-semibold rounded-md">
                        <svg
                          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                          width="24"
                          height="24"
                          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                          fill="none"
                          stroke="currentColor"
                          strokeWidth="2"
                          strokeLinecap="round"
                          strokeLinejoin="round"
                          className="-ml-1 mr-2 h-5 w-5"
                        >
                          <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
                          <polygon points="16.24 7.76 14.12 14.12 7.76 16.24 9.88 9.88 16.24 7.76"></polygon>
                        </svg>
                        <span>Here we go</span>
                      </button>

        </Sidebar_Users>
        <BottomNavigation />
      </>
    );
  }
  
  export default Baseline;
```

I'm a bit confused about creating the timer function with state management - is there a specific library of method for this? Following the examples in the tutorial emphasize using state in a class based function, should i just use a class or can i do the same with a normal function

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be libraries for timers, which are quite common in many applications; but I'll leave that to you to google yourself.

You want to be using `setTimeout`, a comprehensive tutorial on that in react functional components can be found [here](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/settimeout-in-react-components-using-hooks).

**TL;DR**
A generic timer solution usually looks like this.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (triggerTimeout) // some conditional to trigger the timeout to run
  {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      // do anything, this block runs after the timeout has "expired"
      // could even set state
      setSomeState(someNewState);

    }, 1000) // timeout expires in 1000 ms
    // make sure to clear the timeout on component unmount to avoid memory loss issues
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
    // this callback function runs only on component unmount, not re-renders
  }
}, [triggerTimeout]);
```